# The System process loads the system by 30% when idle windows 11

Tags: laptop, windows-11, window, hp

I am using windows 11 22h2 and for the second time in a month after reinstalling the system I encountered this problem:

System process(ntoskrnl.exe) starts to load the CPU when the user is not active, yes, I walk away from the computer and after 5 minutes I hear a hum, I see a load of System process 30%, and it never stops at all, it can at least the whole day so hum. It started back in November, with the update on 22H2, I reinstalled the system, it worked for a month, and then it started humming again. I already made a boot usb ten, but I would really like to cure this strange problem without reinstalling the system, comrades, your ideas, what is this unknown shit and how to fix it? Remarkably when I move my mouse for example the load drops immediately.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I suggest running deep antivirus scans with multiple products, including [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

Answer (score 0):

> second time in a month after reinstalling the system

I suspect you are installing some legacy or incompatible software. I have had Windows 11 for 18 months and no issue like this.

I suggest once again do a fresh install.

Then go slow adding packages.  Install first known good software (Office 365, Adobe, newest iTunes) and check. Then add your printer with known Windows 11 Driver.  Stop there and test for a few days.

Now add remaining software looking for legacy software breaking things.

This is not a Windows 11 issue (18 months, 3 current machines - 2 Production and 1 Insider) and no issues.